# How to limit token receiver callers to accepted token address?

Tags: solidity, hardhat, rsk

I want to create a payable token
which includes a function `transferAndCall(TokenReceiver to, uint256 amount, bytes4 selector)`.
By calling this function, you can transfer tokens to the `TokenReceiver` smart contract address,
and then call `onTransferReceived(address from,uint tokensPaid, bytes4 selector)` on the receiver,
which in turn invokes a function specified in the`bytes4 selector` on the receiver.

Note that this is similar to/ inspired by [ERC1363](https://eips.ethereum.org/EIPS/eip-1363).

Here is a simplified version of my receivable token:

```
import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";
contract MeowToken is ERC20 {
  constructor() ERC20("MeowToken", "MEO") {
    ERC20._mint(msg.sender, 10_000_000);
  }
  function transferAndCall(
    TokenReceiver to,
    uint256 amount,
    bytes4 selector
  ) external {
    ERC20.transfer(address(to), amount);
    to.onTransferReceived(msg.sender, amount, selector);
  }
}
```

And this is a token receiver:

```
contract TokenReceiver {
  address acceptedToken;
  event PurchaseMade(address from, uint tokensPaid);
    
  modifier acceptedTokenOnly () {
    require(msg.sender == address(acceptedToken), "Should be called only via the accepted token");
    _;
  }
    
  constructor(address _acceptedToken) {
    acceptedToken = _acceptedToken;
  }
    
  function onTransferReceived(
    address from,
    uint tokensPaid,
    bytes4 selector
  ) public acceptedTokenOnly {
    (bool success,) = address(this).call(abi.encodeWithSelector(selector, from, tokensPaid));
    require(success, "Function call failed");
  }

  function purchase(address from, uint tokensPaid) public acceptedTokenOnly {
    emit PurchaseMade(from, tokensPaid);
  }
}
```

I want to make sure that public functions on the receiver are **only** called via the payable token.
For this reason I added `acceptedTokenOnly` modifier to both of them.
However after adding the modifier my test began to fail:

```js
it('Transfer Tokens and call Purchase', async () => {
    const tokenAmount = 100;
    const tx = meowToken.transferAndCall(
      tokenReceiver.address,
      tokenAmount,
      tokenReceiver.interface.getSighash('purchase'),
    );
    await expect(tx)
      .to.emit(tokenReceiver, 'PurchaseMade')
      .withArgs(deployer.address, tokenAmount);
});
```

```
1) Transfer and call
       Transfer Tokens and call Purchase:
     Error: VM Exception while processing transaction: reverted with reason string 'Function call failed'
```

Why does this happen?
How to make sure the receiver's functions are invoked only by the accepted token?

For reference, I am developing and testing smart contracts in Hardhat and deploying on [RSK](https://developers.rsk.co/).

Answer (score 9):

When you're doing this:

```js
(bool success,) = address(this).call(abi.encodeWithSelector(selector, from, tokensPaid));
```

you're making an external call, meaning that `msg.sender` will become `address(this)`.

Now the modifier `acceptedTokenOnly` during function `purchase` will fail since `msg.sender` isn't the token anymore.

Suggested changing the function to this:

```js
  function purchase(address from, uint tokensPaid) public {
    require(msg.sender == address(this), "wrong sender");
    emit PurchaseMade(from, tokensPaid);
  }
```

Answer (score 7):

The problem is, you are using low level `call` method, here:
​

```
    (bool success,) = address(this).call(abi.encodeWithSelector(selector, from, tokensPaid));
```

​
This changes the value of `msg.sender` inside `onTransferReceived` from the accepted token to the receiver itself.

Here is one way to achieve what you want:
​
Replace `call` with `delegatecall`.
This will solve your problem instantly.
Unlike `call`, the `delegatecall` will invoke your function on behalf of the caller smart contract:
​

```
  function onTransferReceived(
    address from,
    uint tokensPaid,
    bytes4 selector
  ) public acceptedTokenOnly {
    (bool success,) = address(this).delegatecall(abi.encodeWithSelector(selector, from, tokensPaid));
    require(success, "Function call failed");
  }
```

Answer (score 5):

Apart from switching from `call` to `delegatecall`, as mentioned in @Juan's answer, there is a more "manual" approach:
​
Do not use `call` altogether, and instead invoke the functions by name.
This can be accomplished using an `if ... else` control structure that compares the `selector` parameter with the intended function selector (`purchase`):
​

```
  function onTransferReceived(
    address from,
    uint tokensPaid,
    bytes4 selector
  ) public acceptedTokenOnly {
    if (selector == this.purchase.selector) {
      purchase(from, tokensPaid);
    } else {
      revert("Call of an unknown function");
    }
  }
```

​
While this is more tedious to do, it might be preferable from a security point of view.
For example, if you wish to white-list the functions that you allow to be called through
this mechanism.
Note that the approach using `call`/ `delegatecall` exposes a potential vulnerability
for arbitrary (and possibly unintended) function execution.